# How to read a file several lines at a time with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file, io

I'm learning Ruby, and I'm trying to read a file in a similar way to the `more` command in a Linux terminal.  I have a crude version here:

```
f = File.open("#{file}")
while buffer = f.read(2048) 
    print buffer
    STDIN.gets
end
f.close
```

This works, but has a few problems, the main one being the buffer does not depend on the line, so it often cuts the current line, waits for input, and puts the rest of the line on a new line.

Is there a better way to read a file several lines at a time?  (Bonus question: is there also a better way to wait for the user?  I'm clearly abusing `STDIN.gets`.)

Comment: One normally reads a text file a character at a time, a line at a time or "slurps" the whole thing into a string.  If you use one of the first two methods, Ruby will grab a chunk of the file and cache it, so that it doesn't have to immediately go back to the file when you ask for the next character or line.  Therefore, you're probably not going to enhance efficiency by doing what you want to do.  There may be a way to control the cache size, but I don't know about that.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's not really about efficiency, I simply need to be able to read the file on the terminal.  Printing the entire file at once makes it difficult to read, but printing it one line at a time is too slow, so I'm trying to find an effective way to print several lines and wait for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following.

**Code**

```
def more(fname, lines: 23, clear: false)
  f = File.open(fname)
  loop do
    system "clear" if clear
    lines.times { line = f.gets; (puts line) if line }
    puts "\nPress Enter to continue, Q, Enter to quit"   
    case gets.chomp
    when "q", "Q" then return
    else return if f.eof?
    end
  end
end
```

The operation of the method should be self-explanatory. There are two optional arguments:

- `lines`: number of lines to display at a time, with a default.
- `clear`: if truthy (default `false`), terminal is cleared before each group of lines is displayed. `system "clear"` works with OS X (Mac). Other operating systems may require `system "cls"` or something else.

Ruby will close the file upon returning from the method.

**Example**

First let's construct a test file:

```
FNAME = "t"
str = "It was the best of times,..."
File.write(FNAME, 200.times.map { |i| "#{i}: #{str}"  }.join("\n"))
```

Now let's print it to the screen, five lines at a time, clearing the screen before each group of lines is printed:

```
more FNAME lines: 5, clear: true
```

The screen is cleared and the following is displayed:

```
0: It was the best of times,...
1: It was the best of times,...
2: It was the best of times,...
3: It was the best of times,...
4: It was the best of times,...

Press Enter to continue, Q, Enter to quit
```

After pressing Enter, the screen is cleared and the following is displayed:

```
5: It was the best of times,...
6: It was the best of times,...
7: It was the best of times,...
8: It was the best of times,...
9: It was the best of times,...

Press Enter to continue, Q, Enter to quit
```

After pressing "Q", Enter (or "q", Enter), the screen is left unchanged and the method returns.

Comment: This seems is quite an effective solution!  I especially like the idea of having an optional "clear" argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
f.each_line do |buffer|
  print buffer.chomp
  STDIN.gets
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with my own solution.

```
f = File.open(file)
f.lines.each_with_index do |line, index|
    if (index+1) % 25 == 0     #Every 25 lines
        STDIN.gets             #Wait for user input
    end
    print line
end
f.close
```

This lets the user read a portion of the file and continue on.  I'd still rather not use `STDIN.gets`, but it works.